# FirebaseAuth object initial value is not null

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Here is my code

```
 private FirebaseAuth uFirebaseAuth;
    private TextView loginEmail;
    private TextView loginPword;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uFirebaseAuth = uFirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(uFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //user is already signin.
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DriverMainScreen.class));
       }`
```

FirebaseAuth doesn't get a null value, and on my other activiy it does. 
do you know what causes this? i keep getting a string instead like "zzbkg@" along with 4 digis.